# Mjölnir malfunction

Tags: support, closing, dupehammer

I saw a question which was wrongfully tagged with several irrelevant tags, one of which is the [general-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-topology) in which I have closure superpowers. I retagged the question as [elementary-set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory) in which I also have closure superpowers.

Soon after the OP admitted to having asked the question yesterday and just posted it again because they didn't receive an answer. I voted to close as a duplicate, but I was notified that while I have closure powers in the set theory tag, since I was the one editing it in, they don't apply here.

Shouldn't my powers in the original tagging have applied?

Comment: in the movie Thor, I think Kat Dennings calls it Meow-Meow. See if I can substantiate that. "Darcy: [mispronounces Mjölnir] Myeuh-muh? What's Myeuh-muh?

Darcy: Look! Look, it's "Myeuh-muh"!
[points to a mythology book, specifically a page with a drawing of Mjölnir]" http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0188123/quotes

Comment: Will, yes that is a well-known fact.

Comment: Well, until you said that, I felt special.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, as meanwhile the deciding factor are the **current** tags, but the voter must not have been involved in the tagging.

Source: [It looks like the duplicate banner changed. How does it work now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268278/it-looks-like-the-duplicate-banner-changed-how-does-it-work-now)

Comment: Well. I'm not retagging anything before vetting something is a duplicate. Not to mention that it's annoying the retag was overwritten by subsequent edits.

Comment: First World Problems. :-)

Comment: I never claimed otherwise. :-)